# Double vlan tagged packet handling by IXGBE driver

Tags: linux, vlan

I have a setup where the a vlan tag is added by the switch to an already tagged packet.

Size of the packet entering the switch is 1518 bytes( including ethernet and VLAN tag), the switch adds an additional vlan and the size of the packet becomes 1522 bytes.

The MTU of the interface at the receiving interface is 1500(Linux box).
The ixgbe driver is dropping the packets at the receiving interface as long_length_errors.

I checked the code, and ixgbe allows packets of maximum size (MTU+ethernet header + Vlan) 1500+14+4= 1518 bytes.

Is there a way to handle this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You should able to strip off the VLAN tag with `ethtool` as below,

```
ethtool -K|--offload DEVNAME    Set protocol offload
    [ rx on|off ]
    [ tx on|off ]
    [ sg on|off ]
    [ tso on|off ]
    [ ufo on|off ]
    [ gso on|off ]
    [ gro on|off ]
    [ lro on|off ]
    [ rxvlan on|off ]
    [ txvlan on|off ]
    [ ntuple on|off ]
    [ rxhash on|off ]
```